# Linear approximation of a random vector (X,Y) in the form of Y = aX + b

Tags: probability, random-variables, linear-regression

## Problem

I have a random variable vector (X,Y) whose joint mass function is given by the below table (X = j, Y = k).

[image]

Additionally, the correlation of the vector is given by :
E[XY] = probability of X = Y (so s + t according to the table). s + t = 0.62

Let W = g(X) where g(X) is the linear estimation of Y with respect to X.
So W = g(X) = aX + b.

Determine the mass function of W.

What I tried so far :

## Determine the covariant:

$ Cov = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)$

$ E(X) = 1*(0.07+t) + 2*(0.13+0.12) = 0.57 + t $

$ E(Y) = 0.18 + t $

$ ==> Cov = t^2 + 0.75t - 0.52$

## Find alpha

$a = \frac{COV(X,Y)}{VAR(X)}$
with $VAR(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$
(best linear predictor)

## My issue

By resolving the above equations, I still cannot get rid of the "t" variable. I don't know how I'm supposed to find a real number for "a" and "b" if I don't have the values for s and t, unless I missed something.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you given that $E(XY)=s+t$? You can also calculate $E(XY)$ from the table to be $1\cdot t + 2\cdot 0.12 = t+0.24$. If it's true that $E(XY)=s+t$, then you can solve for $s$, and therefore you can deduce $t$ because all the probabilities in the table must sum to $1$.

Comment: Your comment makes a lot of sense. My issue was not finding the formula for E(XY). How did you find it ? I'm sure I'm overlooking something. Edit: Yes, E(XY) = s+t is given.

Comment: Use the formula $E(XY)=\sum_j\sum_k jk P(X=j, Y=k)$. As you visit every cell in the table, you multiply the value of $XY$ in that cell by the mass reported in that cell, then add up.

Comment: Wow, how did I not come across that. Thank you for your help. I will proceed and report back with the rest of the problem.

Comment: Now that that's settled, I am trying to find the best non-linear approximation of X as a function of Y. The formula is :

$h(Y) = E[X|Y = y]$ Any idea how I can determine that conditional expectancy ? The "Y = y" part is throwing me off.

Comment: Since there are two possible values for $Y$, you have to compute two numbers: (a) $E(X|Y=0)$ and (b) $E(X|Y=1)$. The general formula is $E(X|Y=y)=\sum_jjP(X=j|Y=y)$. So to compute (a) you will write $E(X|Y=0)=0\cdot P(X=0|Y=0) + 1\cdot P(X=1|Y=0) + 2\cdot P(X=2|Y=0)$. To compute conditional probabilities like $P(X=j|Y=k)$ you use $P(X=j|Y=k) = P(X=j,Y=k)/P(Y=k)$